# Unable to index pages in indexed_search TYPO3 6

Tags: search, typo3, web-crawler, indexed

I'm using `indexed_search, indexed_search_mysql` and [crawler](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/crawler) extensions for my website. I created a `crawler` record under `Crawler Configuration` and ran it. This crawls through all the pages successfully.

Configurations `index_enable and index_externals` are set true

The problem is none of the crawled stuff are showing up in the `index` tables. The `info>Indexed Search` shows all the pages as 'not indexed'.

indexed_search only works when `disableFrontendIndexing is set false` . But for this I'd have to visit every page.

Are there any other configurations that i'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Indexed Search only indexes pages that are cached. So you might wanna check if something like

```
config.no_cache = 1
```

is set. In that case you wont get anything indexed. You schould also clear all caches before crawling through your pages, so they have to be cached again.

If its still not working, you can try if

```
config.index_enable = 1
```

and

```
page.config.index_enable = 1
```

makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

In standard configuration the crawler is only writting the pages to index into a queue. You have to run it over "Add Proccess". Did you do this?

[image]

or over cli:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh crawler
```

there is an option to do it in one run:

/usr/bin/php /var/www/example.ch/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh crawler_im 597 -d 9 -conf yourconfititle -o exec

More info on about cli in the docu here:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/crawler/ExtCrawler/ExecutingTheQueue/BuildingAndExecutingQueueRightAway(fromCli)/Index.html